# How do I increment an array value up to another array value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
//value of currency denominations
    var currencyTable = [100, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01];

//total cash at each currencyTable denomination in the cash register 
    var cashInDrawer = [100, 60, 20, 55, 90, 4.25, 3.1, 2.05, 1.01];

//total change due
    var changeDue = 96.74;
```

My goal is to return the correct change from the cash available from the greatest cash denomination to the lowest.

I can't figure out how to increment a value in **currencyTable** up to the available amount in **cashInDrawer** while **changeDue** >= **currencyTable[i]**.

I've managed so far:

```
var total = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < currencyTable.length; i++){
  while (changeDue >= currencyTable[i]){
    total.push(currencyTable[i])
    changeDue-=currencyTable[i];
  }
 }return total;
```

but this only returns:

```
[20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
```

where I want to return:

```
[60, 20, 15, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.04]
```

Somewhere in the loop I realize changeDue is being changed into a repeating decimal but I found a temporary workaround using *.toFixed()*.

Comment: Don't push `currencyTable[i]` on every round of the `while` loop. Instead sum the values up and only push the sum after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely on the right path. But instead of calling `push` each time in the inner loop, you need to *add to* the amount you pushed the previous time when you're looping. Probably the easiest way to do that is to have a variable you add to, and then push at the end. You also have to check against `cashInDrawer` and reduce `cashInDrawer` when you add to `total.

There is a problem inherent in this: You're using JavaScript's number type to deal with money. But JavaScript's number type isn't suited to dealing with money, IEEE-754 binary floating point values have notorious imprecision issues in the decimal realm, such as the famous:

```js
console.log(0.1 + 0.2); // 0.30000000000000004
```

And that comes up in this problem. If we just apply the logical fixes above, we get (see `***` lines):

```js
//value of currency denominations
var currencyTable = [100, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01];

//total cash at each currencyTable denomination in the cash register 
var cashInDrawer = [100, 60, 20, 55, 90, 4.25, 3.1, 2.05, 1.01];

//total change due
var changeDue = 96.74;

var total = [];
for (let i = 0; i < currencyTable.length; i++){
    let amount = 0;                                                 // ***
    while (changeDue >= currencyTable[i] && cashInDrawer[i] > 0) {  // ***
        amount += currencyTable[i];                                 // ***
        changeDue -= currencyTable[i];
        cashInDrawer[i] -= currencyTable[i];                        // ***
    }
    // I assume you want to push the amount even if it's 0
    total.push(amount);                                             // ***
}
//return total;
console.log(total);
```

Notice that the last entry is `0.03`, not `0.04`. That's because `changeDue` is getting more and more imprecise as we go, which we can see if we log it:

```js
//value of currency denominations
var currencyTable = [100, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01];

//total cash at each currencyTable denomination in the cash register 
var cashInDrawer = [100, 60, 20, 55, 90, 4.25, 3.1, 2.05, 1.01];

//total change due
var changeDue = 96.74;

var total = [];
for (let i = 0; i < currencyTable.length; i++){
    let amount = 0;                                                 // ***
    while (changeDue >= currencyTable[i] && cashInDrawer[i] > 0) {  // ***
        amount += currencyTable[i];                                 // ***
        changeDue -= currencyTable[i];
        cashInDrawer[i] -= currencyTable[i];                        // ***
        console.log(changeDue);
    }
    // I assume you want to push the amount even if it's 0
    total.push(amount);                                             // ***
}
//return total;
console.log(total);
```

At the end, `0.009999999999994869` is not `>=` `0.1` and so the loop ends early.

See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) for various approaches to fixing that.

One common solution is to use the numbers `* 100` and keep rounding. (Sometimes you might use `* 10000` and then round back to two decimal places, etc.) Here's the general idea, tweak as necessary:

```js
//value of currency denominations
var currencyTable = [100, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01];
currencyTable = currencyTable.map(entry => Math.round(entry * 100));   // ***

//total cash at each currencyTable denomination in the cash register 
var cashInDrawer = [100, 60, 20, 55, 90, 4.25, 3.1, 2.05, 1.01];
cashInDrawer = cashInDrawer.map(entry => Math.round(entry * 100));     // ***

//total change due
var changeDue = 96.74;

changeDue = Math.round(changeDue * 100);                                // ***
var total = [];
for (let i = 0; i < currencyTable.length; i++){
    let amount = 0;
    while (changeDue >= currencyTable[i] && cashInDrawer[i] > 0) {
        amount += currencyTable[i];
        changeDue -= currencyTable[i];
        cashInDrawer[i] -= currencyTable[i];
    }
    // I assume you want to push the amount even if it's 0
    total.push(amount);
}
//return total;
for (const entry of total) {
    console.log(entry / 100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. At one point when I was working on this I had the idea that I'd need another placeholder variable to push values of currencyTable[i] before pushing to the total onto the total array but for whatever reason I never did.

Answer (score -1):

You need to aggregate the number of items of currency. Try following

```
var total = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < currencyTable.length; i++){
        var cCount = 0;
        while (changeDue >= currencyTable[i]){
            cCount++;
            changeDue-=currencyTable[i];
        }
        total.push(cCount*currencyTable[i])
    }
    return total;
```

Comment: This is okay as far as it goes, but still leads to the wrong result for multiple reasons (it doesn't handle `cashInDrawer`, doesn't handle floating point imprecision, ...)